# How to include minted file with "[ ]" in filename

Tags: minted, external-files

I use bash to generate list of files and make sections

```
git ls-files *js | 
while read  i; do                
    name=${i//\/\\/ }
    name=${name//_/\\_}             
    echo "\newpage" >> $tex_file 
    echo "\section{$name}" >> $tex_file 
    echo "\inputminted[linenos,tabsize=2,breaklines]{text}{'$i'}" >>$tex_file
done &&
```

and have pdglatex error

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmtt.fd) [8] [9] [10] [11]
[12] [13]) [14]
Overfull \hbox (83.28297pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 36--36
|[]\T2A/cmr/bx/n/14.4 drafts/zakaz/CustomerOrdersExchange/parsers/InformationRe
gisterRecord.js|
(./_minted-tmp/42C1FB8BAA58B770CBB63CD3829666B6.pygtex [15]) [16]sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
system returned with code 512


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.40 ...ext}{'server/api/1c/[shopid]/exchange.js'}

?
```

I need `[]` in file names because of https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes

Comment: Have you tried with an extra pair of braces?

Comment: What kind of braces I need ? [[shop]]?

Comment: Around the bane of your file in the inputminted command.: Instead of {'$i'} try with {{'$i'}}

Comment: Also I would change the newpage with clearpage.

Comment: `{{'$i'}} ` works. i can accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with filenames and such, that includes delimiters or special characters like brackets, commas, etc., you need to put an extra pair of brackets to protect them.

For your case:

```
git ls-files *js | 
while read  i; do                
    name=${i//\/\\/ }
    name=${name//_/\\_}             
    echo "\newpage" >> $tex_file 
    echo "\section{$name}" >> $tex_file 
    echo "\inputminted[linenos,tabsize=2,breaklines]{text}{{'$i'}}" >>$tex_file
done &&
```

should work.